# Iframes point same website, common code downloaded

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a big about IFRAME, let's take a following example:
I have a website "A" with n pages, every page contains an undefined number of iframes which point to a website "B", all iframes point to a different page of the website "B". My question is:
since the iframes point to the same website "B",
since every pages contain reference to the same common items (css,javascript),
what happen to the common items when the iframes are loaded? 
Are the common items downloaded once, or are they downloaded everytime that an iframe is loaded?

thanks

michee

Comment: depends on the browser setting s and the headers sent with the resources, but typically the browser would cache them and not download them again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how they are served from the server. If they have the expirey set correctly, then the browser will use the version it already has.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields):
Expires:    Gives the date/time after which the response is considered stale (in "HTTP-date" format as defined by RFC 7231)

E.g.
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Permanent: standard

The is also [Cache-Control](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

---

This doesn't always guarente that the cached version would be used, as a hard refresh CTRL-F5 (some browsers CTRL-R) will override it.

Additionally, some browsers can be set to ignore the cache.